# PySpark multithreaded read Py4JNetworkError: Answer from Java side is empty

Tags: python, pyspark

I keep getting the following error when trying to parallel read data from Snowflake using jdbc in PySpark. 
It works fine when using really small number of threads (eg. 50) but occurs north of 100 or so. 
The cluster has tremendous resources 6k c/40T.
I have tried playing with the config but no PnC helped. Here are the error, spark config, and code respectively.

[image]

[image]

[image]